# Org Mode: org-lookup-* functions missing

Tags: org-mode, org-table

The functions `org-lookup-first`, `org-lookup-last`, and `org-lookup-all` do not seem to be available to me. These functions are documented at the following link: [Lookup Functions](http://orgmode.org/manual/Lookup-functions.html#Lookup-functions).

I can't look them up in the help system, and they don't work when I try to use the functions replicating tutorials. It seems like something is preventing these functions from being available. I don't think that there is anything in my config that would be doing this though. Does anyone have any ideas why this might be happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your org is too old. These functions were added to pre8 version of org. Upgrade your org package to version 8 and org-table should be automatically included.

Answer (score 1):

You need to load the `org-table` library. You can customize the `org-modules` variable to include it.

Comment: They still are not available after doing this.

Comment: You need to reload org to get it to load the `org-table` library via `org-modules`. If they are still not available perhaps your org-mode version is too old.

Comment: Also - these are elisp functions, not formulas for use in the spreadsheet.

Comment: Still not available after requiring org-table. I don't think version is the issue as I do see in the code the macro that is supposed to define the functions. For what it's worth,  Org is version 7.9.3f. Emacs version is 24.3.1.